# text or sequence from the text file using batch?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have the file called `file.txt` which contains,

```
American 9876543 america@gmail.com
Australian 7674840 Australia@mail.com
Indian 9364906 india@ymail.com
Chinese 6383936 china@mail.com
Japanese 9363839 Japan@hotmail.com
```

Now i want to filter three things from this file as output in another text file.

For example,

output `file1.txt` - need to contain all mail id's

```
america@gmail.com
Australia@mail.com
india@ymail.com
china@mail.com
Japan@hotmail.com
```

output `file2.txt` - need to contain all numbers

```
9876543
7674840
9364906
6383936
9363839
```

output `file3.txt` - need to contain only the sequence word starting at A,

for example,

```
American
Australian
```

For this i tried using FC command and Findstr commands.. And i have No idea how to do these with those commands correctly.

Please help.. Thanx in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I want to filter three things from this file as output in another text file

You don't need `fc` or `findstr` to do this. A simple `for /f` command will suffice.

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3" %%a in (`type file.txt`) do (
  echo %%a >> file3.txt
  echo %%b >> file2.txt
  echo %%c >> file1.txt
  )
endlocal
```

Example usage:

```
> type file.txt
American 9876543 america@gmail.com
Australian 7674840 Australia@mail.com
Indian 9364906 india@ymail.com
Chinese 6383936 china@mail.com
Japanese 9363839 Japan@hotmail.com

> test

> type file1.txt
america@gmail.com
Australia@mail.com
india@ymail.com
china@mail.com
Japan@hotmail.com

> type file2.txt
9876543
7674840
9364906
6383936
9363839

> type file3.txt
American
Australian
Indian
Chinese
Japanese
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.